# How to fix "send e-mail" via Delphi Winapi.Mapi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, registry, mapi, regedit

I've updating Microsoft Office from version 2016 to version 2019.
After that my Delphi-Program can't open new Outlook mail window.
The program uses SimpleMapi via Winapi.Mapi to start Outlook.

The Outlook App is setted as Standard-App for sending mails.
The windows registry don't contain the MAPI-Key in the standard like before.
I've tried to add the following MAPI Keys to the windows registry, but without success.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem]
"MAPI"="1"
"MAPIX"="1"
"OLEMessaging"="1"
"CMC"="1"
"MAPIXVER"="1.0.0.1"
"CMCDLLNAME32"="mapi32.dll"
```

The reason why I have tried this, is that Winapi.Mapi search in the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem for the MAPI keys to load the MAPI32.dll of the setted standard mail application.
The MAPI is allegedly not available if the Winapi.Mapi tried to load it.
A remark: The "mailto"-functionality works fine.

So my program works fine with the older versions of Microsoft Office like 2016 and earlier, but not with the version 2019. 
The Question is: what is the reason for the failure? is the registry configuration a reason for that or maybe the obsolated Embarcadero lib?

I hope the problem description was clear enough. 
Hope you can help me.

Comment: `mailto` calls Outlook.exe with some command line parameters. Open a command prompt, and type `ftype mailto` and hit enter to see exactly what it does. (Using `ftype.exe` is much faster than drilling down through the registry, and pairing it with `assoc.exe` can quickly identify what is associated with a file extension and what will handle that filetype.) And no, EMBT has nothing to do with anything; MS has been tightening what programs can automate for several years now for security/malware prevention reasons. It's the reason recent Office versions don't use ActiveX any longer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer. But the "mailto" function do not support attachments, right?

Comment: No, mailto doesn't support attachments. I only provided info on mailto because you specifically mentioned in your question that it was working while MAPI didn't.

Comment: I tried to manually add the MAPI entries. If I run my program and want to send an e-mail, I get an info message by Windows. The message contains something like: there is no standard app selected for this action. After I close the message, Outlook window will open.(in some cases) [sorry for my terrible english]

Comment: Sounds to me like MS removed MAPI support from the current version of Outlook. You'll have to check the developer's documentation for Outlook (available at http://learn.microsoft.com somewhere) to see what alternatives it supports.

Comment: You can do this via pure COM/ActiveX (`GetActiveOleObject/CreateOleObject`), this still works with o365/2019. Mapi support is a bit of a problem because of the fact that your application needs to have the same bitness as the office installation.

Answer (score 1):

Just came a cropper with this issue under windows 10/office 365

Add MAPI string value of '1' to this Key instead.

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Messaging Subsystem

restart application and should be back in business.

Comment: My Existing application started working when i put this key. Thanks .  For the record i am using Mozilla Thunderbird (Version:102.12.0 ) as the MAPI Client

Answer (score 0):

```
unit uAutomationSendMessage;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

function SendMessageViaOLE(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               Recipients : TStringList = nil;
                               AttachList : TStringList = nil) : Integer;
function AutomationSendMessage(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               recipients : TStringList = nil;
                               AttachList : TStringList = nil) : Integer; OverLoad;
function AutomationSendMessage(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               recipients : String = '';
                               AttachFile : String = '') : Integer; OverLoad;

implementation

uses
  OutlookSecMan,
  Outlook2010,
  ComObj,
  ole;

procedure SleepForXXXMiliSecend(MiliSecunda : Integer);
Var
  CurTime  : Integer;
  UntilMax : Integer;
begin
  UntilMax := Trunc(MiliSecunda / 10);
  if UntilMax < 5 then
    UntilMax := 5;
  For CurTime := 0 to UntilMax Do
  begin
    Sleep(05);  {10 cose it work more then excepted}
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;


function SendMessageViaOLE(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               Recipients : TStringList = nil;
                               AttachList : TStringList = nil) : Integer;
const
  olMailItem = 0;
var
  OlSecurityManager: TOlSecurityManager;
  CurItem   : Integer;
  Outlook   : OLEVariant;
  MailItem  : Variant;
  OLCreated : Boolean;
begin
  Try
    OlSecurityManager:= TOlSecurityManager.Create(Application);
    OLCreated := False;
    try
      Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
    except
      Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application') ;
      OLCreated := True;
    end;
    SleepForXXXMiliSecend(100);
    MailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem) ;
    SleepForXXXMiliSecend(100);
    //MailItem.Recipients.Add('johndoe@hotmail.com') ;
    MailItem.Subject := Subject;
    if UseHtml then
      MailItem.HTMLBody := Body
    else
      MailItem.Body := Body;
    if Assigned(Recipients) then
    begin
      for CurItem := 0 to Recipients.Count - 1 do
        if Trim(Recipients.Strings[CurItem]) <> '' then
          MailItem.Recipients.Add(Recipients.Strings[CurItem]);
    end;

    if Assigned(AttachList) then
    begin
      for CurItem := 0 to AttachList.Count - 1 do
        if Trim(AttachList.Strings[CurItem]) <> '' then
          MailItem.Attachments.Add(AttachList.Strings[CurItem]);
    end;
    MailItem.Display(False); //True=Send Immedeate

    SleepForXXXMiliSecend(100);
    If OLCreated Then
      VarClear(Outlook);
  Finally
    OlSecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings := False;
  End;
end;

function AutomationSendMessage(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               Recipients : TStringList = nil;
                               AttachList : TStringList = nil) : Integer;
const
  olMailItem = 0;
  olByValue = 1;
Var
  CurTest   : Integer;
  CurItem   : Integer;
  //Outlook   : OleVariant;
  Outlook: Outlook2010.TOutlookApplication;
  OlSecurityManager: TOlSecurityManager;
  vMailItem : variant;
  mRecipient, mSubject, mBody, mAttachement: String;
Begin
  Result := -99;
  Try
    OlSecurityManager:= TOlSecurityManager.Create(Application);
    //Try
    //  Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    //Except;
    //  Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
    //End;
    Outlook := TOutlookApplication.Create(nil);
    OlSecurityManager.ConnectTo(Outlook.Application);
    OlSecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings := True;
    vMailItem := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
    SleepForXXXMiliSecend(20); // avoid Call was rejected by callee.
    //vMailItem.Recipients.Add('test@hanibaal.co.il');
    For CurTest := 0 To 10 Do
    begin
      Try
        vMailItem.Subject := Subject;
        Break;
      Except;
        // wait somw more for prevent - Call was rejected by callee.
        SleepForXXXMiliSecend(20); // avoid Call was rejected by callee.
      End;
    end;

    if UseHtml then
      vMailItem.HTMLBody := Body
    else
      vMailItem.Body := Body;

//MailItem.Recipients.Add('someone@yahoo.com'); // Type=1 olTo
//MailItem.Recipients.Add('joesmoe@yahoo.com').Type := 2; // olCC
//MailItem.Recipients.Add('alice@yahoo.com').Type := 3; // olBCC
    if Assigned(Recipients) then
    begin
      for CurItem := 0 to Recipients.Count - 1 do
        if Trim(Recipients.Strings[CurItem]) <> '' then
          vMailItem.Recipients.Add(Recipients.Strings[CurItem]);
    end;

    if Assigned(AttachList) then
    begin
      for CurItem := 0 to AttachList.Count - 1 do
        if Trim(AttachList.Strings[CurItem]) <> '' then
          vMailItem.Attachments.Add(AttachList.Strings[CurItem]);
    end;

    Try
      IF ShowModal Then
      begin
        IF vMailItem.display(True) Then
        begin
          Result := 0 {Message sent}
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        //vMailItem.Send;
        IF vMailItem.display(False) Then
        begin
          Result := 0 {Message sent}
        end;
      end;
    Except
      on e : System.SysUtils.Exception do
      begin
        Result := 1; {Message not sent}
        ShowMessage('Sending mail fail - ' + e.Message);
      end;
    End;
  Finally
    OlSecurityManager.DisableOOMWarnings := False;
    Try OlSecurityManager.Free; Except; End;
    VarClear(vMailItem);
    Outlook := nil;
  end;
end;

function AutomationSendMessage(Subject    : WideString;
                               Body       : WideString;
                               UseHtml    : Boolean = False;
                               ShowModal  : Boolean = True;
                               recipients : String = '';
                               AttachFile : String = '') : Integer;
Var
  recipientsList : TStringList;
  AttachListList : TStringList;
begin
  recipientsList := TStringList.Create;
  AttachListList := TStringList.Create;
  Try
    recipientsList.Add(recipients);
    AttachListList.Add(AttachFile);
    result := AutomationSendMessage(Subject,
                                    Body,
                                    UseHtml,
                                    ShowModal,
                                    recipientsList,
                                    AttachListList);
  Finally
    recipientsList.Free;
    AttachListList.Free;
  End;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet! I think this is a nice solution too(don't testing it). 
But I have choosed an other way to realize it. 
I check the windows registry for the dll's of all mapi-clients installed on the machine. For this I use the TRegistry - Obj. SearchPath is the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\Mail. After that I have the choice of which one I or the user prefer to use.